# Two Tomcat Services in a VM

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, virtual-machine

Installed two Tomcat 9.0.60 services in a single windows VM with diff ports(8080 & 9090), did the same config changes, deployed same version of applications which shares the same DB. I found that the Tomcat with port 9090 is dead slow and I couldn't even open the application. It takes ages to load a single page.

Tried all the ways (Changing Tomcat versions, deploying diff version of Application and changing heap). None resolved my issue.

So, I deleted the 9090 Tomcat service and copied the 8080 Tomcat to 9090 Tomcat's location and started. It works as expected.

any idea what went wrong ?

Comment: Well it's too late to know now.

Comment: I've the copy of the Tomcat which I deleted(8080)

Comment: I've compared all the files in all the directories, all are same.